# Oracle 1 = meaning

Tags: sql, oracle

What does it mean from the '`1 =`' in the following sql block?

```
<sql_query_1>
AND 1 = (sql_query_2);
```

Comment: Most people would prefer the other direction, which is more readable: `AND (sql_query_2) = 1`

Comment: I seem to remember some earlier versions of Oracle (pre-11g maybe) could not parse `(subquery) = literal` and could only handle `literal = (subquery)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your query_1 expects that query_2 returns `1` as result in order to meet the `WHERE` condition and return some data.

If query_2 returns something different than `1`, this condition will evaluate to *false* and query_1 won't return anything.